# crayon brush effect in processing

Tags: html, canvas, processing

I was trying to implement a crayon brush for drawing in processing canvas. [This tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) did the thing using HTML5 canvas. So far, the logic seems to be loading a transparent crayon texture over a particular color. How to achieve this effect in processing?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like it by creating an image of what you want the crayon to be like, a .PNG whit transparent background, the color and texture of the crayon, all in a circle shape.
Then you just have to draw that image on the method onMousePressed().

Regards